# Why is my Rails web app calling the wrong action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm diving into Ruby on Rails and I'm experiencing a weird bug, using Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.8.7.  Using the generated scaffold code, my "Show" action is getting called when I'm expecting my "Destroy" action to get called.  Here's the code...

routes.rb

```
webappdotcom::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

actual HTML code that is rendered in browser

```
<td><a href="/projects/12" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
```

server output when I click on the "Destroy" link

```
Started GET "/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Oct 20 23:39:37 -0500 2010
  Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE ("projects"."id" = 12) LIMIT 1
Rendered projects/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 13.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

You can see the "ProjectsController#show" action is being called, but I want the "Destroy" action to be called.  Also, I noticed the browser isn't displaying the confirmation message "Are you sure?" either.  Any ideas what could be causing this or what I'm missing?

Thanks so much!

Comment: in the `link_to`, does changing `project` to `@project` help?

Comment: unfortunately no, that causes the rendered html to read "<a href="/projects"...>, which causes the index action to be called.

Comment: unrelated to the issue, but doesn't Rails 3+ require Ruby 1.9.2 ?

Comment: found out that Ruby 1.8.7 is the minimal requirement and not 1.9.2. Also, 1.9.1 seems to crash Rails 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Rails 3 changed the way it uses javascript in forms. It used to add an `onclick` method to the link, but that goes against unobtrusive javascript.  Now it just sets some tag attributes, and hooks into it with javascript in another file.

That page's layout (which is probably application.html.erb unless you've changed it) needs to have this line in the head section:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

If this line is missing from your layout, that's the problem.  Another possible cause could be if you've added the jQuery library to your app without adding the rails-specific jQuery library.  Let me know how this works.

Comment: well actually, I was doing both of those things.  I had commented out the defaults include tag and, in its place, put links to non-rails-specific jQuery library.  Anyhow, fixing both of those things fixed the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you [link_to with :method=>:delete not working ( Rails 3 )](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38460). Although in that article the `edit` is getting called instead. But the solution should work for `show` as well.